# Best practice for displaying text in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awk

I'm completing a university assignment in java. It consists of some inputs, a block of text and a graph dependent on the inputs.

In my course I've been taught to display text using drawString directly onto a graphics object. Surely there is a better way than this! Is there a component/container that can be used to display uneditable text?

**Should I be using drawString to output textual information or some other way?**

Comment: Review [Using Text Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) and consider posing a more specific question.

Comment: Be sure to check with your tutor/professor before using something you were not taught.  As silly as using `drawString()` is, it is seemingly specified by those that will be assigning marks.

Comment: I'm not worried about getting a low grade Was thinking of writing it in Clojure, but thought that might be a bit much. Thanks for the link trashgod!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I guess you _can_ put a [graph](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#Histogram) in a `JLabel`! :-)